# Having a Monad and a type of the same name

Tags: haskell, monads

I've got an assignment where a type and a monad have the same name (Rand) and it appears to be messing up making a function that can unwrap the monad (i.e. `Rand Something -> Something`) since it appears to be choosing the wrong one. Is there something I can do to stop this?

Comment: Many Monads are type constructors (and *all* Monads are types of kind `* -> *`), so this is normal. You really need to post more details for us to have a good chance of giving you good advice. At the minimum, give us enough code to reproduce the problem and the exact error you're getting.

Comment: Usually the function to unwrap the monad has the name prefixed with `un` or `get` or `run`, like `runReader`, `getConst`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import qualified Rand as R

data Rand = Rand ...

foo :: R.Rand Rand -> Rand
```

Altough frankly, having it named the same is very confusing and I'd avoid that.

Comment: I agree it is confusing, unfortunately that's how the work was set so I needed the workaround. Cheers